# Understanding the code from C++ program

Tags: c++

I was trying to understand a code from a coding website solution but was unable to figure out a lot of things. I could understand the BIT and fenwick part but whatever I couldn't understand I have written down it below:
The source of this code is **http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/1816336** 
It would be really helpful if someone explains the concepts that instead of using standard defined input output functions why we tend to use these :

```
char ioSpace[500000 * 17 + 128];
unsigned popcnt(unsigned x)
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    return __builtin_popcount(x);
    #else
    unsigned ret;
    asm("popcntl %1, %0;":"=r"(ret) :"r"(x));
    return ret;
    #endif
}

unsigned readUInt(char*& readPos)
{
    unsigned num = 0;
    unsigned c;
    while ((c = *readPos++) >= '0')
    num = num * 10 + (c - '0');
    return num;
}

template<unsigned D>
void writeDigit(char*& writePos, unsigned& advance, unsigned& num)
{
    unsigned digit = num / D;
    num %= D;
    if (digit)
    advance = 1;
    *writePos = digit + '0';
    writePos += advance;
}

void writeUInt(char*& writePos, unsigned num)
{
    unsigned advance = 0;
    writeDigit<100000>(writePos, advance, num);
    writeDigit<10000>(writePos, advance, num);
    writeDigit<1000>(writePos, advance, num);
    writeDigit<100>(writePos, advance, num);
    writeDigit<10>(writePos, advance, num);
    advance = 1; // for zero number
    writeDigit<1>(writePos, advance, num);
    *writePos++ = '\n';
}
```

and then in the main input function :

```
    read(STDIN_FILENO, ioSpace, sizeof(ioSpace));
```

Can someone explain me the whole procedure because I have been trying to incorporate such styles in my C++ programming and have inevitable failed to do so because of lack of understanding .

Comment: I consider myself a fairly competent programmer (after all, I've been doing some sort of programming stuff for over 30 years). I have absolutely no idea what this code is meant to solve. It may be the perfect solution to something, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I see no evidence that this code is a good exemplar that merits your study. The complete lack of any comments in itself makes me mistrust the code. You don't say where you are stuck with this code, if you really want to understand it step through it in a debugger and it should become clear. To get you started, some observations about read.

It seems pretty clear that the readUint() and writeUint() methods are working against a buffer, presumably that ioSpace, though you don't show the actual calls so we can't be sure, but your

```
  read(STDIN_FILENO, ioSpace, sizeof(ioSpace));
```

shows the iospace obtaining date from STDIN. Quite what happens if the file is bigger than iospace isn't clear from what you show. Nor is what error handling is done.

The code for readUint() goes:

```
 while ((c = *readPos++) >= '0')
```

Which grabs the next character, and increments the readPosition. When we see that we should immediately wonder when we stop. in this case when the character c is not

```
 >= '0'
```

in other words when the character we see is less than ascii '0' so that could be any characters such a '&' or '#', but probably the author is expecting a newline '\n' as that seems to be what they terminate the number with in writeUint() - see what I mean about lack of comments? Then

```
c - '0'
```

yields the numeric value of the character '9' - '0' is the ascii code for 9 less the ascii code for 0, 57 - 48 , which of course is 9.

```
while ((c = *readPos++) >= '0')
    num = num * 10 + (c - '0');
```

we then build the decimal value by mutiplying by 10 and adding our most recently read value.

Now this code is vulnerable to a file containing letters. Look at what would happen if you had a line such as

```
 23A4\n
```

So you need to have some reason to trust your input if you are using this code.

Writing just grabs the individual digits from the number by calling the writedigit() function.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmn... I'm pretty sure that the readUInt function is used to convert a string number to actual number, i.e. equivalent to atoi() function. I think the WriteDigit is the reverse, but I'm not sure.